# Java EWS API works under windows but not on linux

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I have compiled and executed some proof-of-concept code using the java-ews-api, and have had success when running it under windows.  THe same code times out when I run it under linux.  Firewalls seem as if they are the most likely suspect, but I can ping the exchange server from eh Linux server.

Could you offer suggestions as to what I should test or research?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the latest EWS Java API from https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api ?

Comment: I am indeed.  I just downloaded it this week.

Comment: I have tried fiddling around with proxy settings, just in case that was the issue (-Dhttp.proxy=... or -Dhttps.proxy=...., along with username, port and password).  No combination of proxy settings seems to make a difference.     Is there some debug / verbose flag I could enable in ews to assist in debugging?  Are there some Unix commands I could execute to test connectivity (other than ping)?

Comment: There is a way to turn on tracing for the JAVA API, to see what goes over the wire to Exchange.  But, for the issues you are seeing, you need help from a Unix expert, as the issue seems to be w/ networking settings.  So, I am not sure how much the EWS tracing would help.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the situation some, it became clear to me that it's simply a firewall issue.  The simplest way for me to test connectivity to my Exchange server (using https) was via netcat:

netcat webmail.mydomain.com 443 < /dev/null; echo $?

That will print zero (0) if port 443 is open on that host, and a one (1) if it is closed.